# WordPress Multi Language Help

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website that needs to have its articles in multiple languages. The authors will be writing the articles themselves so I don't need an automatic translation tool. The plan is that a user can choose a language from a drop-down list which will then show the different language. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google gives

http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/

It's a plugin for wordpress that does exactly what you're after. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wpml.org/ awesome plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

[mLanguage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mlanguage/) is another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who stumbles upon, there is a new plugin named Multilanguage: https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/multilanguage